# Use the localized SE site's language for links to the Creative Commons' licensing pages

Tags: feature-request, localization, timeline, creative-commons

Any [post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/372091/timeline) contains a link to the Creative Commons' license pages. For modern posts, it is https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/. As far as I see, there are many different languages that you can choose on that site:

> [image: CC BY-SA languages]

Since some Stack Exchange sites have a localized non-English interface, it could be very desirable on those sites to link to the Creative Commons license version which matches the site's language. For instance, on [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1351198/timeline), it could target the Russian version: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.ru